# How to create grid / heatmap images in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, graphics, data-visualization

Looking for a way to visualize data by generating simple graphics in Ruby.

Is there a gem that allows you to crete simple images, such as a checkerboard?

It should be:

- Easy to use
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Not require Rails
- Saves image in at least one common format such as jpeg, gif or png

EDIT: After doing more research, I found that the name of the chart is grid or heatmap. Found this [RubyVis](http://rubyvis.rubyforge.org/examples/1_basic_grid.html) library.

Comment: Another interesting option is Processing: you can easily develop powerful visualizations with the Processing IDE.  The generated byte code can be invoked from JRuby (similar to Ruby 1.9) and it's fun to work with this combination.

Comment: I noticed you found an answer that you liked. Consider adding it as an answer below and marking this question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) is well-documented and supports several common file formats. It's an interface to ImageMagick, so you need to have that installed to use it.

Comment: RMagick is the de-facto image library for Ruby, but the interface is bewildering and confusing to say the least. The documentation does provide some good examples, though.

Comment: After searching for different solutions, this one turned out to be surprisingly easy.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Lowis gave a talk at Ruby Manor conference in London in December 2009 on doing visualizations in Ruby. Perhaps you might be interested in his [slides](https://github.com/chrislo/data_visualisation_ruby/raw/master/slides.pdf)[pdf] and [examples](https://github.com/chrislo/data_visualisation_ruby)?